# i can't pass values from source to target in primefaces picklist

Tags: jsf, primefaces

That's my first post.I am trying to make a picklist for my primefaces application.I can see the values listed in source part and also i can pass source values to target panel in the screen.But in the server side,tariffListForDestination (binded to target panel in picklist) still remains empty.But in the screen everything is ok.And also when i debug my application and made a breakpoint in the ontransfer method and pass a source object to target,i see no value in the event.getItems(event TransferEvent).

I am sending related part of my code below.

Thanks for reply.

DÇ

my xhtml code snippet:

```
        <p:pickList id="pojoPickList" value="#{serviceCopyInsertBean.tariffList}" var="tariff" effect="bounce"
                itemValue="#{tariff}" itemLabel="#{tariff.cpcmOfferName}"    converter="tmp2TariffDescMappingConverter"
                showSourceControls="true" showTargetControls="true" showCheckbox="true"
                showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true"     filterMatchMode="contains" >

    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Starting</f:facet>

    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{serviceCopyInsertBean.onTransfer}"/>

        <p:column style="width:75%;">
        #{tariff.cpcmOfferName}
    </p:column>

</p:pickList>
```

My converter Tmp2TariffDescMappingConverter

```
      import java.util.ArrayList;
      import java.util.List;
      import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
      import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
      import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
       import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
      import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;
      import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
      import com.i2i.st.entity.Tmp2TariffDescMapping;

    @FacesConverter("tmp2TariffDescMappingConverter")
    public class Tmp2TariffDescMappingConverter implements Converter {

private static List<Tmp2TariffDescMapping> tmp2TariffDescMappingDB;

static {
    tmp2TariffDescMappingDB = new ArrayList<Tmp2TariffDescMapping>();

}

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
    if (submittedValue.trim().equals("")) {
        return null;
    } else {
        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(submittedValue);

            for (Tmp2TariffDescMapping tmp :tmp2TariffDescMappingDB) {
                if (tmp.getCpcmOfferId() == number) {
                    return tmp;
                }
            }

        } catch(NumberFormatException exception) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Tmp2TariffDescMapping"));
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return String.valueOf(((Tmp2TariffDescMapping) value).getCpcmOfferId());
    }
}
```

}

My JSF bean

```
         private DualListModel<Tmp2TariffDescMapping> tariffList=new                              DualListModel<Tmp2TariffDescMapping>();
         private List<Tmp2TariffDescMapping> tariffListForSource=new ArrayList<Tmp2TariffDescMapping>();
     private List<Tmp2TariffDescMapping> tariffListForDestination=new ArrayList<Tmp2TariffDescMapping>();

                tariffList=new DualListModel<Tmp2TariffDescMapping>(tariffListForSource, tariffListForDestination);
```

Comment: Could you show `onTransfer` method on bean as well? It is starting with `public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event)` right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you iterating over tmp2TariffDescMappingDB in the getAsObject(). How did you filled that list?

You should search into tariffList.getTarget() and tariffList.getSource() to look the both sides of the pickList. Something similiar to this generic one:

```
    public T getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    ...
    if (component instanceof PickList) {
        DualListModel<T> dl = (DualListModel) ((PickList) component).getValue();
        for (T t : dl.getTarget()) {
            //search here
        }
       for (T t : dl.getSource()) {
            //maybe here too
        }
     ...
```